# In what aspects is sleep considered 1/60th of death?

Tags: death, sleep

> אש אחד מששים לגיהנם...
>   דבש אחד מששים למן
>   שבת אחד מששים לעולם הבא
>   **שינה אחד מששים למיתה**
>   חלום אחד מששים לנבואה
>
> ...sleep is one-sixtieth of death ([Brochos 57b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.57b.13?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he))

In what aspects is sleep considered 1/60th of death?
(Ma Nafkah minah?)

Comment: Impurity, requiring hand washing upon waking (according to one understanding).

Comment: Your eyes are closed and you're unaware of your surroundings. Those are two ideas. I can't vouch for the suggested ratio, as no dead person has told me what that's like.

Comment: I heard the ratio came from *bitul b'shishim*. Sleep is 1/60 of death, Shabbat is 1/60 of the world to come. 1/60 is the different between something that is and something that gets diluted. If Shabbat is lived well, it is like the world to come. If you sleep well, it feels like nothing is happening (like death). Not sure if there are sources for the idea but it makes for a wonderful compliment when hosted on Shabbat. Tell the *baalat habayit* that in her house, one clearly knows on which side of 1/60 one is cc: @DanF

Comment: @mbloch Thanks for the suggestion. But, I'm also not that stupid to commit suicide in my own home ;-)